# How to 301 redirect from url with post id to permalink with post name (slug)?

Tags: posts, categories, permalinks, redirect, slug

my posts have urls of two different types: one with post id and other with post slug:

```
/post/789
/post/my-post-slug
```

i'm doing this using:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'post/(\d+)/?',
    'index.php?p=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

and setting up permalinks using %post_name%.

both `/post/123` and `/post/my-post-slug` open the same html page.

is it possible to make wordpress return the 301 redirect to `/post/my-post-slug` when accessing `/post/123`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible. add a `template_redirect` hook handler:

```
add_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_post_to_canonical_url');

function redirect_post_to_canonical_url(): void
{
    if (!is_single()) {
        // do not redirect nothing else except posts
        return;
    }


    $canonicalLocation = get_permalink();
    $requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $currentLocation = home_url('/') . substr($requestUri, 1);
    if ($currentLocation === $canonicalLocation) {
        // prevent from infinite redirect loop
        return;
    }

    wp_redirect($canonicalLocation, 301);
}
```